# Adding vue 3 to existing web forms ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

In vue 2, in order to incorporate vue into an existing web forms ASPX page you just had to add the proper script tag. Something like this :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
```

Can you do this with Vue 3? I've been researching how to incorporate vue 3 into existing web forms application, like ASPX pages, and can't find anything on it. Can anyone show me how to incorporate vue 3 into an ASPX page?

Comment: could you show how you used to do that with vue 2?

Comment: see OP @BoussadjraBrahim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

or

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

The Vue package makes multiple packages available:

- vue.cjs.js
- vue.cjs.prod.js
- vue.esm-browser.js
- vue.esm-browser.prod.js
- vue.esm-bundler.js
- vue.global.js
- vue.global.prod.js
- vue.runtime.esm-browser.js
- vue.runtime.esm-browser.prod.js
- vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js
- vue.runtime.global.js
- vue.runtime.global.prod.js

You'd pick whichever one work best, but the simplest way to go is to use the `vue.global.js` during development and `vue.global.prod.js` in prod

---

### Example

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  template: document.getElementById("appTemplate").innerHTML
})

app.component('my-component', {
  template: document.getElementById("componentTemplate").innerHTML,
  props:{name:{default: "‍♂️"}}
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>

<template id="appTemplate">
  <h1>APP</h1>
  <my-component name="world"></my-component>
</template>

<template id="componentTemplate">
  Hello {{name}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! On the ASPX page, once you put the vue 3 reference, how would I just "dynamically" print out hello world using vue 3? (simplest way) @Daniel

Comment: added example, you can use composition API or class-based components, or even mix if you like. Porting from Vue 2 should be straight forward, but you may find some gotchas, especially around 3rd party libraries

Comment: Thanks @Daniel - Was your example using composition API or class based components?

Comment: it's not using composition API (that would have `setup()` function)

Answer (score 1):

Based on official docs you could use [CDN](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#cdn) as follows :

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```